# ng-repeat filter with condition angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

This is my code :

```
 <option ng-repeat="name in names" value="{{names.name}">
    {{names.name | limitTo:10 }}
 </option>
```

How can I add a condition:

```
if( names.name.length > 10) { 
     //add ... point after name displayed 
}
```

to get result `<option value="Alexander Bradley">Alexander ... </option>`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to limit the length of the name. If it's because you only have so much width, I would do this in css instead.

Comment: *a similar question with answers below link*


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095727/limit-the-length-of-a-string-with-angularjs/28262387#28262387

Comment: *similar question with results below link*

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095727/limit-the-length-of-a-string-with-angularjs/28262387#28262387

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own filter that does this and include the length parameter if you like.

```
.filter("ellipses", function () {
    return function (item) {
        if (item.length > 10) {
            return item.substring(0, 10) + " ..."
        }
        return item;
    };
});

<option ng-repeat="name in names" value="{{names.name}">
    {{names.name | ellipses }}
</option>
```

---

You can include the length argument as well and even use `limitTo` itself:

```
.filter("ellipses", ["$filter", function ($filter) {
    return function  (item, limit) {
        if (item.length > limit) {
            return $filter("limitTo")(item, limit) + " ...";
        }
        return item;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This is the right answer, though you could probably give more info about how to set up filters, since the OP may not know.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you asked for.. Limiting the name to 10 chars and then adding a "..." to the end of it if it exceeds 10 characters.  This is how I would do it.  (Also fixed some of your syntax errors).

```
<option ng-repeat="name in names" value="{{name}}">
    {{name.length <= 10 ? name : name.substring(0, 10) + "..."}}
</option>
```