# Limit characters and have three dots after in angular js and ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working with AngularJS and Ionic, I'm using the ng-bind-html to pull data from a rest API. I want to limit the amount of characters but also have three dots after the characters to show the user there is more to read...

So far I have:

```
<p ng-bind-html="item.excerpt | limitTo: 100"></p>
```

But this just limits the characters and cuts them off.

Comment: this question has already been answered
[there][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095727/limit-the-length-of-a-string-with-angularjs

Comment: none of them methods describe a work round for ng-bind-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with the https://github.com/sparkalow/angular-truncate. Real simple and easy to use and it can be used with ng-bind-html

Answer (score 23):

For a pure angular approach, you can do something like this:

```
{{(item.excerpt | limitTo: 100) + (item.excerpt.length > 100 ? '...' : '')}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: In the new angular versions, there's 'slice' pipe instead of the 'limitTo' pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Answer (score 13):

Honestly your question seems more oriented to css

You can truncate text, and add dots (...) using "ellipsis"

Example, if you have inside html something like:

```
<p class='ellipsis'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur<p>
```

and you add something like this on css :

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

p.block {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Result is something like :

```
<p class='ellipsis'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</p>
```

If you want implement a button "read more", on click, just remove the 'ellipsis' class, and all text will be displayed.

More info there :
[Ellipsis info](http://mattsnider.com/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/)

Answer (score 2):

In my project I came up with this filter:

```
angular.module('yourModule').filter('limitToDots', function($filter) {
    return function(input, limit, begin, dots) {
        if (!input || input.length <= limit) {
            return input;
        }

        begin = begin || 0;
        dots = dots || '...';

        return $filter('limitTo')(input, limit, begin) + dots;
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<span>{{ text | limitToDots : 50 }}</span>
<span ng-bind="text | limitToDots : 50"></span>
<span ng-bind-html="text | limitToDots : 50"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using older ionic version which doesn't have 'limitTo:' on binding 
like what @c0r3yz 's answer, try this in your html

```
{{ item.excerpt.length > 100 ? item.excerpt.substring(0,100)+"..." : item.excerpt }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Text truncate class in Bootstrap did the job for me.

Note: The container should have a fixed width or column proportion for this to work

Ref:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow