# How to ignore the text after some particular length using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fetching some data from database and displaying them inside table. I need when any column value will text character will more than some certain length, it will display up to that length and other will be replace with dot (`i.e-.....`).

I am providing my code below.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>

<th>Specification</th>

</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="pro in productDataList">
<td>{{$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{pro.specification}}</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

In the above code for `Specification` contains some paragraph. I need here the `paragraph` should display up to `30` character, if it exceeds more than that the remaining text will replace with `....`.

Comment: What do you have tried so far? After 1s googling: 1. http://sparkalow.github.io/angular-truncate/ 2. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit the length of a string with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095727/limit-the-length-of-a-string-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo).

You can simply do

`{{ pro.specification | limitTo: 30 }} {{ pro.specification.length > 30 ? '...' : '' }}`

to limit to exactly 30 characters, and if there are more than 30, it will add ellipsis to the end

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
    {{ pro.specification.substr(0,30) + '...' }}

Comment: surely @UtsavShah's solution is the Angular way doing it. I prefer to use it as my solution as it has less typing :)