# How to truncate messageText in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a broadcast message and i want to truncate the message displayed if it exceeds the length allowed into something like:

original message:

```
some text message that is very very very very very very very very long
```

into something like this:

```
some text message.....
```

Here is the code

```
<div data-ng-repeat="message in messages | limitTo: limit">
 <label>{{message.MessageDateTime|ctime|date:'dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a'}}
 <b>{{message.MessageSender}}: </b>{{message.MessageText}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `LimitTo` filter

Comment: Why not use `css` property: `overflow: ellipsis`

Comment: I just follow from the post that JanR posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095727/limit-the-length-of-a-string-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a custom filter of your own.

```
module.filter('truncate', function () {
        return function (input) {
            if (!input) {
                return '';
            } else if (input.length > 10) {
                return input.slice(0,10); //limit to first 10 characters only
            }
             else
              return input;
        };
    })
```

And you can use it in html as

```
<div data-ng-repeat="message in messages | limitTo: limit">
 <label>{{message.MessageDateTime|ctime|date:'dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a'}}
 <b>{{message.MessageSender}}: </b>{{message.MessageText | truncate}}</label>
</div>
```