# Angular: limitTo pipe not working

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am trying to run `limitTo` pipe on Angular2 on a string:

```
{{ item.description | limitTo : 20 }}
```

And I get the following error:

```
The pipe 'limitTo' could not be found
```

### Is it possible that this pipe was removed in Angular2?

This is my `app.module`

import { TruncatePipe }  from './limit-to.pipe';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: GridComponent
      },
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent, 
    TopNavComponent, 
    GridComponent,
    TruncatePipe
  ],
  providers: [
    PinService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My grid component that is using the pipe:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }   from '@angular/router';

@Component({    
    moduleId : module.id,
    selector: 'my-grid',    
    templateUrl : 'grid.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'grid.component.css']
})

export class GridComponent  implements OnInit{


    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private gridService: GridService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

My Pipe definition:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe  } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'limitToPipe'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, limit: number) : string {

    let trail = '...';

    return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
  }

}
```

And finally my template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" class="grid-item">
  <p class="simple-item-description">
    {{ item.description | limitToPipe :  20 }} 
  </p>                
</div>
```

Comment: The `limitTo` is not available in Angular 2 as a common part, as seen [in the API reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiFilter=pipe&query=pipe). You can however build your own pipe.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First you need to create a pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'limitTo'
})
export class TruncatePipe {
  transform(value: string, args: string) : string {
    // let limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[0], 10) : 10;
    // let trail = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '...';
    let limit = args ? parseInt(args, 10) : 10;
    let trail = '...';

    return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
  }
}
```

Add the pipe in the module.ts file

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import {  TruncatePipe }   from './app.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
  ],
  declarations: [
    TruncatePipe
  ],
  exports: [ 
  ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Then use the pipe in the binding code:

```
{{ item.description | limitTo : 20 }}
```

Demo [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/LlViY10FWQW2xHfniw9k/)

Comment: I tried that, and I keep getting:     
"
[ts] Argument of type '{ moduleId: string; selector: string; templateUrl: string; pipes: typeof TruncatePipe[]; styleUrl...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pipes' does not exist in type 'Component'.
import TruncatePipe"

Comment: Did you inject the pipe in you module 'declarations' ? i.e, @NgModule

Comment: Add pipe in the module not in the component.

Comment: I added it to NgModule, but keep getting in my component the following error: "The pipe 'limitTo' could not be found"

Comment: Check the pipe name is 'limitTo' or anything else. Please provide your pipe source code.

Comment: first - thank you very much for your help. It appears that the problem is that my pipe was not reloaded by the watch process.. extremely weird

Answer (score 81):

In order to answer to your question if it was removed: yes and no. `limitTo` seems to be removed, but there is a `slice` pipe which basically does the same as `limitTo` and can be used on strings aswell as on lists. It also gives you the oppurtunity to start your limitation at a given start index, which is neat.

In your case a simple `{{ item.description | slice:0:20 }}` would be enough. Unless you want to gain more experience writing your own pipe, which I even encourage ;)

Source and Documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html

Comment: Exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 9):

I added this code to make more sense

```
{{ item.description | slice:0:20 }}{{ item.description.length > 20 ? '....read more' : '' }}
```

to show that the data is sliced and contains more data that is hidden

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ng2-truncate](https://github.com/yellowspot/ng2-truncate) instead

It has more options such as: truncate by words, truncate by characters, truncate left side (...abc)....

```
$ npm install ng2-truncate --save
```

Declarations

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TruncateModule } from 'ng2-truncate';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<p>{{ "123456789" | truncate : 3 }}</p>'
})
export class MyComponent {

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ TruncateModule ],
  declarations: [ MyComponent ]
})
export class MyApp { }
```

Component

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: '<p>{{ "123456789" | truncate : 3 : "..." }}</p>',
    ...
})
```

Result:

```
<p>123...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Simple soultion for limit the records

```
<li *ngFor="let item of _source| slice:0:3; let ind=index;">
   {{item.description}}
</li> 


Here slice:0:3 --> 3 is the 3 records length means only first three records will be displayed.
```