# ngBind shrink long text with

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-bind

Is it possible for ngbind to resize or sobstitute a portion of text with ... if text is too long?

```
<div class="cell-content" ng-bind="order.productName"/>
```

my problem is that the productname is sometimes to long and it deforms the cell enlarging it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095727/limit-the-length-of-a-string-with-angularjs

Comment: try `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to truncate the text but I would say the `limitTo` directive is the right way to go